# How to make presentation with java or swift code with highlighting in Keynote?

Tags: macos, highlighting, presentation, keynote

I have a swift-code and java-code, I want show code with highlighting in my keynote presentation? How do I do this?

Comment: A cropped screen shot from an IDE will do the trick.

Comment: I must have possibility to edit

Comment: Switch between Keynote and a full-screen IDE using virtual desktops.  (I've done this a lot, that really is the least jarring way to accomplish this effectively in front of an audience.  A simple three-finger swipe on the touchpad, or whatever the gesture is for you, and you're good to go.  *Any* time spent mucking around with windows or formatting or anything like that will drain an audience's attention.)

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to make simple presentation with coloured code in google docs, [it](https://romannurik.github.io/SlidesCodeHighlighter/) was perfect fit for me.